# Rearranging of summands of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let be $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k$ a series which attains a complicated form and we must show that it is convergent.

I am wondering if the following is a legit strategy:

Let's assume that we have spotted a nice way to rearrange the summands $c_k$ of the partial sums $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}c_k$. This yields a new partial sum $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}a_j$ which attains an easy form such that we can immediately see that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j$ is absolutely convergent. We know that each rearrangement of $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j$ is also absolutely convergent, hence $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k$ is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in theory that will work: if $b\colon\Bbb N\longrightarrow\Bbb N$ is a bijection such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{b(n)}$ converges absolutely, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely too. Besides, both series have the same sum.